Selenium router throwing "Unable to execute request: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException" error, and browsers get empty capabilities
We have hub node selenium grid in AWS cloud, and the grid version is 4.20. Node containers are up and running and when I trigger protractor tests nodes gets empty capabilities and no tests runs. When I see the container logs the router has below exception.

"log":"18:27:17.699 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "5570f6cb7eeda9c2f4cab81d3bc04008","eventTime": 1716834437695416131,"eventName": "exception","attributes": {"exception.message": "Unable to execute request: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\nBuild info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.336-253.554.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '17.0.11'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown","exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\nBuild info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.336-253.554.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '17.0.11'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute0(JdkHttpClient.java:396)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute(JdkHttpClient.java:352)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:54)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.security.AddSecretFilter.lambda$apply$0(AddSecretFilter.java:40)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.remote.RemoteNewSessionQueue.addToQueue(RemoteNewSessionQueue.java:104)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.lambda$new$0(NewSessionQueue.java:68)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:192)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.execute(NewSessionQueue.java:128)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:87)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:63)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:87)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.lambda$apply$0(EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.java:34)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:63)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$NestedRoute.handle(Route.java:270)\n\tatorg.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:346)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:69)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:63)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:63)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\u002fjava.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute0(JdkHttpClient.java:379)\n\t... 43 more\n","exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException","http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.remote.RemoteNewSessionQueue","http.host": "10.148.120.44:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "300","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.target": "\u002fsession"}}\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-05-27T18:27:17.699445534Z"}

Same tests are working fine from grid version 4.11.
Selenium-protractor tests
